# Is there any way to set an elif statement inside the init() function in the class?

Tags: python, class, if-statement

I have code which targets to use if-elif-else functions to filter inputs.

So the target is to make a filtering code that filters three integer input to get a value from 0 to 90. The number exceeding 90 should be valued as 90 and negative numbers should be valued as 0. The inputs however, are linked into mother class 'self'.

So I picked the if-elif-else since it was the most preferable choice, but I couldn't find the right way.

Code is

```
class student_scores(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id, math_score, english_score, science_score):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.math_score = math_score
        self.english_score = english_score
        self.science_score = science_score
        # We need some codes here to match the conditions.
    def print_scores(self):
        print("%s 's math, english, science score is %d, %d, %d respectively."%(self.name, self.math_score, self.english_score, self.science_score))

student1 = student_scores("Kay", 20141, 50, 110, -10)
student2 = student_scores("Lisa", 20304, 55, 70, 65)
student3 = student_scores("Rin", 29850, 100, 11, 4)
```

And the result should be printed as

```
Kay's math, english, science score is 50, 90, 0 respectively.
Lisa's math, english, science score is 55, 70, 65 respectively.
Rin's math, english, science score is 90, 11, 4 respectively.
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can use conditional logic in an `__init__()` method? Yes, you can.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditionals fine within a constructor, but you don't need them. You can cap values using `min`/`max` functions, for example

```
    self.math_score = min(max(0, math_score), 90)
    self.english_score = min(max(0, english_score), 90)
    self.science_score = min(max(0, science_score), 90)
```

If the input is negative, `max(0, value)` returns `0`. If the input is above 90, then `min(value, 90)` returns `90`.